# plotting sin(x) graph in Matlab - strange results

Tags: matlab, plot, trigonometry

Hi I'm trying to plotting graphs in Matlab and I getting strange results:
i should do graphs of y=a*sin(b*x+c)
when a,b,c changing from graph to graph..
but as u can see when I'm changing the 'b' value to a big one
the graph in figure app become strange.

and one of the causes that make the graphs strange is the 'N' value in the matlab function: x=linspace(x0,xt,N)
why for example when I'm changing N to 200 the graph going crazy?
what exactly 'N' doing maybe i didn't get it :(

so here is my code, the problem is in 'figure 4' (section 'c'), the graph there is not looking like sin(x) 
while in figure1,2,3 it was all good.

[when offering me a solution, please consider i need the graph with 3 full cycles].

code:

```
%------a------%
vm1=20;
vm2=41;
vm3=79;
f=44;
w=2*pi*f;

t=linspace(0,6*pi,120);  %6pi for 3 cycles
v1=vm1*sin(w*t+pi/3);
v2=vm2*sin(w*t-pi/4);
v3=vm3*sin(w*t);

plot(t,v1,t,v2,t,v3);
ylabel('v(t)[V]');
xlabel('t[sec]');
legend('v_1(t)','v_2(t)','v_3(t)');

%-----b-----%
vsum=v1+v2+v3;
figure;plot(t,vsum,'linewidth',2);
ylabel('v(t)[V]');
xlabel('t[sec]');
legend('v_s(t)');

%-----c-----%
f1=200;
w1=2*pi*f1;
f2=200*3.2;
w2=2*pi*f2;
f3=200*4.3;
w3=2*pi*f3;

v1_new=vm1*sin(w1*t+pi/3);
v2_new=vm2*sin(w2*t-pi/4);
v3_new=vm3*sin(w3*t);
figure;plot(t,v1_new,t,v2_new,t,v3_new);
ylabel('v(t)[V]');
xlabel('t[sec]');
legend('v_1new(t)','v_2new(t)','v_3new(t)');

vsum_new=v1_new+v2_new+v3_new;
figure;plot(t,vsum_new,'linewidth',2);
ylabel('v(t)[V]');
xlabel('t[sec]');
legend('v_s(t)');
```

Comment: You have `pi` in both the `w` and in `t` and then you are multiplying them which gives you `pi^2` inside the `sin` and `cos` functions. Are you sure you need both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function "y=a * sin(b*x+c)" b changes the period of the sine wave, the time it takes to go one full cycle.

The period: T = 2*pi / b

So if you want to have 3 periods you should calculate T and make sure that your t runs from 0 to 3*T.

```
t = linspace(0,6*pi/w1,120);
```